# What is the correct way of validating running code when a particular role accesses a screen?

Tags: user-roles, validation

I'd like to run a series of actions if a particular role accesses a specific screen. For example,

```
if( is_user_logged_in() && ! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) ) {
   if( isset( $current_screen->base ) ) {
      if( $current_screen->id == 'edit-page' ) {
         // Perform some action
```

Or alternatively, should it be crafted as such;

```
if( isset( $current_screen->base ) ) {
   if( $current_screen->id == 'edit-page' &&  is_user_logged_in() && ! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) ) {
      // Perform some action
```

If it's the latter, would it not be more efficient/effective to consider the first option if there are a series of screens?

For instance;

```
if( is_user_logged_in() && ! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) ) {
       if( isset( $current_screen->base ) ) {
          if( $current_screen->id == 'edit-page' ) {
             // Perform some action

          if( $current_screen->id == 'edit-post' ) {
            // Perform some action
```

As opposed to:

```
if( isset( $current_screen->base ) ) {
   if( $current_screen->id == 'edit-page' &&  is_user_logged_in() && ! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) ) {
      // Perform some action

   if( $current_screen->id == 'edit-post' &&  is_user_logged_in() && ! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) ) {
      // Perform some action
```

Would this also be true for examples like the one below?

```
if( is_user_logged_in() && ! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) ) {
    if( isset( $current_screen->base ) ) {
        foreach( $screens as $screen ) {
            if(  $current_screen->id === $screen ) {
                wp_die( __( 'Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.' ), 403 );
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing the number of checks increases the performance of your code, so yes, check `is_user_logged_in()` and `current_user_can()` as few times as you can.

For executing functions depending on the admin page, I'd probably attach  callbacks to [`load-{$pagenow}` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/load-pagenow/) (untested):

```php
function wpse417218_do_something_for_edit_page() {
    if ( 'page' !== get_current_screen()->id ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Do something.
}
add_action( 'load-post.php', 'wpse417218_do_something_for_edit_page' );
```

This will keep everything organized, and also check the user's capabilities only if on the appropriate page.

Comment: is there a particular reason for using the `load-post` vs `current_screen` action?

Comment: is there any additional value in combining `! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' )` with `is_user_logged_in()`? I generally pair them as a sanity check.

Comment: I'd use `load-` to keep organized, and not have all functionality in one callback. I don't think there's value in both checks: if there's no logged-in user, the user won't have any meaningful capabilities.